# Display Sale icon on special price products in magento. Only at homepage it is showing not in all pages

Tags: php, magento

Display Sale icon on special price products in magento. Only at homepage it is showing not in all pages.

Code I have edited in
app/design/frontend/default/template/catalog/product/list.html
from the line number: 95

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"` class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />


<?php 
    // Get the Special Price
    $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
    // Get the Special Price FROM date
    $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
    // Get the Special Price TO date
    $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
    // Get Current date
    $today =  time();

    if ($specialprice):
        if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
?>
        <img src="../images/sale-icon.png" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
<?php  
        endif;
    endif;
?>

</a>
```

This icon is displaying in homepage only not in All product list of pages. How do i display in all pages?

Please help me out of this

Comment: Be careful comparing dates like this!

This assumption will never occur:
`$today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate)`

Because time() gets the complete time and getSpecialToDate() doesn't.

You have to get only the date from time like this:

`$today =  date('Y-m-d');`

And thus convert it to unixtime

Answer (score 3):

This is because you insert the image like this:

```
<img src="../images/sale-icon.png" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
```

The image should be placed in `skin/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/images/` and you should reference it this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/sale-icon.png');?>" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
```

**[EDIT]**
A bit off topic, but good to know: Don't use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())` for each product attribute you need. It slows down the page more than you think. Just edit the attributes you need (special price, special price from and special price to) in the backend set the field `Used in product listing` to `Yes`, reindex everything and you should be able to use directly:

```
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
```

Comment: OK i have placed that as you said. but that is displaying only in homepage products only.. not in inside pages like category pages..Check this URL http://reboot.co.in/shop

Comment: First of all make sure you are using the same template for product on homepage and the ones in the category. If you do then most probably one of your if statements returns false.

Comment: I have no other ideas. Like I've said before, maybe one of your if statements return false. Check which one. That would be a good place to start.